# How to unit test FileContentResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit

I have a method that exports data into CSV file.

```
public FileContentResult Index(SearchModel search)
{    
    ...
    if (search.Action == SearchActionEnum.ExportToTSV)
    {
        const string fileName = "Result.txt";
        const string tab = "\t";
        var sb = BuildTextFile(result, tab);
        return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/tsv", fileName);
    }
    if (search.Action == SearchActionEnum.ExportToCSV)
    {
        const string fileName = "Result.csv";
        const string comma = ",";
        var sb = BuildTextFile(result, comma);
        return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", fileName);
    }
    return null;
}
```

My test, in NUnit:

```
[Test]
public void Export_To_CSV()
{
    #region Arrange
    ...
    #endregion

    #region Act

    var result = controller.Index(search);

    #endregion

    #region Assert
    result.ShouldSatisfyAllConditions(
        ()=>result.FileDownloadName.ShouldBe("Result.csv"),
        ()=>result.ContentType.ShouldBe("text/csv")
        );
    #endregion
}
```

In addition to `FileDownloadName` and `ContentType`, I want to check the content of the `result`.

It seems I should look into `result.FileContents`, but it is a `byte[]`.

How can I get hold of the `result` as a text string?

And is my result saved somewhere as a CSV file in the solution every time I run the test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Index method, you are using the following code to encode the text content as bytes:

```
return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", fileName);
```

To get from the bytes to the original text, you can use:

```
string textContents = new UTF8Encoding().GetString(result.FileContents);
```

The result is NOT saved anywhere as a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV File will not be saved automatically as you do the testing. When you get the response, it is the raw response. It would be up to you to save it.

To convert a binary byte array to a string, you can use

```
string csv = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.FileContents);
```

That is off the top of my head, so may need fixing.